# how to "push back" an non-copyable object into a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

I tried to use push_back and emplace_back, but all failed.

```
class Base30 {
public:
    Base30() = delete;
    Base30(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    Base30(const Base30& other) = delete;

    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Base30> vec;

    Base30 b1 = { 1, 2 };

    //vec.push_back(b1);  // fail

    //vec.emplace_back(1, 2);  // fail

    return 0;
}
```

How to push_back Base30 into this vector?

Comment: You need to make `Base30` *moveable* instead.

Comment: when you delete auto-generated functions, or define a custom destructor you'll need to define/delete all other auto generated functions yourself. So, define any constructors, delete copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator (if your class is non-copyable), define move-constructor and move-assignment operator (or delete them if the class is non-movable). Lastly define a destructor. If you've done all this courtesy of wonderfull C++ language, you can finally push stuff in a vector (or `emplace_back`) them.

Comment: The `emplace_back` line works just fine for me: https://godbolt.org/z/oHu7vF . (however, @Yksisarvinen 's suggestion is a good one)